# How to use Socket.IO in useEffect() statement?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I cam across a strange thing which I don't quite get it.

I have a listener on event `newOrder` which should be received every time when a `newOrder` is emitted from backend. The problem here is that if I use it like this `useEffect(() => { ... }, [])` it will fire only once which somehow make sense but if I use it like `useEffect(() => { ... })` it fires too many times because of the new renders.

My question is how is best to use it in a useEffect to listen every time when a newOrder is received, or is there a better approach?

Here is my code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // WAIT FOR A NEW ORDER
    ws.on('newOrder').then(data => {
      dispatch(addOrder(data));
      dispatch(updateStatus('received'));
    });
    // CLIENT CANCELED
    ws.on('clientCanceledOrder').then(() => {
      dispatch(updateStatus('ready'));
      dispatch(clearPrice());
      alert('Your rider has canceled the order!');
    });

    return () => {
      ws.off('newOrder');
      ws.off('clientCanceledOrder');
    };
  }, []);
```

Here is my SocketClient.js

```
export default class socketAPI {
  socket;

  connect(user) {
    this.socket = io(BASE_URL, {
      query: `type=driver&id=${user}`,
      reconnection: true,
      transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
      rememberUpgrade: true,
    });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log(this.socket.io.engine.id);
        resolve(true);
      });

      this.socket.on('connect_error', error => reject(error));
    });
  }

  disconnect() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.socket.disconnect(reason => {
        this.socket = null;
        resolve(false);
      });
    });
  }

  emit(event, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.socket) {
        return reject('No socket connection. Emit Event');
      }

      return this.socket.emit(event, data, response => {
        // Response is the optional callback that you can use with socket.io in every request.
        if (response.error) {
          return reject(response.error);
        }

        return resolve(response);
      });
    });
  }

  on(event) {
    // No promise is needed here.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.socket) {
        return reject('No socket connection. On event');
      }

      this.socket.on(event, data => {
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }

  off(event) {
    // No promise is needed here.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.socket) {
        return reject('No socket connection. On event');
      }

      this.socket.off(event, data => {
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

then I call this `const socketClient = new SocketClient();` and this

```
`useEffect(() => {
(async () => {
  const isConnected = await socketClient.connect(driver.id);

  dispatch(updateSocketStatus(isConnected));
})();
}, [driver]);` inside my context
```

Comment: Using it with `[]` should not make it fire only once. `.on` statement is adding an event listener. It will work after that everytime you emit the event. Have you tested it?

Comment: @TusharShahi using it with `[]` it will fire only once as I've tested it. Thats my main concern because I thought that it will create a listener and will listen for that event over and over again until will unmount the component.

Comment: It should do that. If it is not maybe your ws is getting reinstantiated every time. That's why it would run only once, cause maybe is a new instance everytime. Can you show how you are defining it

Comment: @TusharShahi I am looking for the id of the socket and doesn't seem to reconnect. Please have a look on my socket implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general promise is **resolved/reject only one time** and then no more. But socket.io can emit more than one message. I suggest you to rework WS wrapper method to add event listener instead of promise

```
  on(event, listener) {
      if (!this.socket) {
           throw 'No socket connection. On event';
      }

      this.socket.on(event, listener);
  }
```